# Android suporta RMI?

Tags: android, rmi

O `Android` suporta o `Java` `rmi`? Estou desenvolvendo na plataforma `Android 4.0`.
Se suportado, poderia por favor. Informa uma matéria ou tutorial de como fazer essa comunicação?

Comment: Estou pesquisando isso para você, mas encontrei um tópico que fala que usar RMI é uma má opção: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110629/android-networking

Comment: estou pesquisando bem para poder tomar uma decisão pelo que achei acredito que isso não seja uma boa pratica

Answer (score 1):

O android não tem suporte para o Java.rmi vi códigos de alguns programadores que implementaram isso no seu app mais não é recomendado ou seja utilize Socket, http para melhor funcionamento do seu app